# Does $(T_nf)(t)\sin(nt)f(t)$ converge weakly to zero?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $X=L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $T_n \in B(X)$ given by $(T_n f)(t)= \sin(nt)f(t)$. I need to identify if $T_n$ converges weakly, strongly or uniformly to $0$.

I have proved that $\sin(nt)$ converges weakly to $0$ in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$. **Can we extend this to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and hence deduce that $T_n$ converges weakly to $0$?**

For strong convergence, we need to see if $\lVert T_n(f) \rVert_{L^2}\to 0$. That is,

$(\int |\sin(nt)f(t)|^2 dt)^{1/2} \to 0$, for any $f\in X$, as $n \to \infty$.

Consider $f(t)=1$ when $t \in (-\pi,\pi)$ and $f(t)=0$ otherwise. Then the above integral converges to $\sqrt{\pi}$. Hence $T_n$ is not strongly convergent and hence not uniformly convergent.

Comment: Yes. Show that it holds on all sets $[-A,B]$, equivalently for all compactly supported $f$.

Comment: Note that you can find some $L$ such that $\int_{|t|>L} |f|^2 < \epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sin (nt)^2 = {1 \over 2}(1-\cos(2 n t))$ we have
$\|T_n f\|^2 = {1 \over 2}( \int |f(t)|^2 dt -\int \cos(2 n t)|f(t)|^2 dt )$. Since
the Riemann Lebesgue lemma shows that $\int \cos(2 n t)|f(t)|^2 dt \to 0$, we see that
$\|T_n f\| \to {1 \over \sqrt{2}}\|f\|$.

Suppose $g \in L_2(\mathbb{R})$, then Cauchy Schwartz shows
that $t \mapsto g(t)f(t)$ is integrable.

Then$\langle g, T_n f \rangle = \int \sin (nt) g(t) f(t) dt$ and
Riemann Lebesgue shows that $\langle g, T_n f \rangle \to 0$.

Comment: This is cool. How about the weak convergence?

Comment: @Kenneth.K: That is just Riemann Lebesgue, see above.